# Maximal Closed Subgroups of $ SU_4 $

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification, finite-groups, lie-groups

What are the maximal closed subgroups of $ SU_4 $?

The full list of maximal subgroups I'm proposing is:

Type I (normalizer of maximal connected subgroup)
\begin{align*}
& U_3 \cong S(U_3 \times U_1) \\
& S(U_2 \times U_2):2 \\
& 4 \circ_2 Sp_2  
\end{align*}
Type II (finite maximal closed subgroup)
\begin{align*}
&4\circ_2 2.A_7
 \\
&4\circ_2 Sp(4,3)
 \\
&N(2^{2(2)+1})
\end{align*}
Type III (normalizer of a subgroup which is connected but not maximal connected)
\begin{align*}
& N(T^3)=S(U_1 \times U_1 \times U_1 \times U_1) : S_4\\
& SO_4(\mathbb{R})\cdot 4 \\
\end{align*}

Note that $ S(U_1 \times U_1 \times U_1 \times U_1) $ is contained in $ S(U_3 \times U_1) $ above. And $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) $ is contained in $ Sp_2 $. However $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) \cdot 4 $ is not contained in $ 4 \circ_2 Sp_2 $.

Note on notation. $ : $ means split extension (semidirect product). $ \cdot $ means nonsplit extension. $ \circ $ denotes central product, in all cases here we have $ 4 \circ_2 H $ is just the group generated by $ H $ and $ iI $ but that group is not a direct product since already $ -I \in H $, we get a central product essentially with two $ H $ components.

Here all the $ N $ denote normalizer. Recall that a positive dimensional (type I and type III above) maximal subgroup of a simple Lie group equals the full normalizer of its identity component.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605784.pdf
classifies all maximal closed subgroups of $ SU_n $ whose identity component is not simple (here trivial counts as simple). According to table 5 the maximal closed subgroups of $ SU_4 $ of this type are:

The normalizer of the maximal torus (row 4 table 5, $ \ell=4, p=1 $)
$$
 N(T)=S(U_1 \times U_1 \times U_1 \times U_1) : S_4
$$
As well as (row 1 table 5, $ p=3,q=1 $ )
$$
S(U_3 \times U_1 )\cong U_3 
$$
and the normalizer of $ S(U_2 \times U_2)= \{\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}:A,B\in U_2,det(A)det(B)=1 \} $ which is a split extension (row 1 table 5 $ p=q=2 $)
$$
< S(U_2 \times U_2),\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 &  0 \end{bmatrix}> \cong S(U_2 \times U_2):2
$$
where the normalizing matrix swaps the two blocks in the direct sum.

Next there is (row 3 table 5, $ p=2 $)
$$
<SU_2 \otimes SU_2, \zeta_8\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}>
$$
where the normalizing matrix swaps the two tensor factors and applies a global phase. Here the identity component $ SU_2 \otimes SU_2 $ contains $ -I=(\zeta_8 SWAP2)^4 $, but does not contain $ iI=(\zeta_8 SWAP2)^2 $, so the full normalizer is the nonsplit extension $ SU_2 \otimes SU_2 \cdot 4 $. This subgroup is conjugate to the normalizer of the standard $ SO_4 $ subgroup
$$
 SO_4(\mathbb{R}) \cdot 4 
$$
and we prefer to write it that way. For more details see

[Is $ SU_2 \otimes SU_2 $ conjugate to $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) $ in $ SU_4 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397313/so-4-mathbbr-and-su-2-otimes-su-2-subgroups-of-su-4?rq=1)

Next, we consider maximal closed subgroups with nontrivial simple connected component.

By dimension, such a subgroup would be isogeneous to $ SU_2,SU_3,Sp_2 $ or $ G_2 $.

There is no 4d irreps of $ SU_3 $ since the dimension of $ SU_3 $ irreps are given by the formula
$$
\frac{(m_1+1)(m_2+1)(m_1+m_2+2)}{2}
$$

Similarly there are no 4d irreps of $ G_2 $ since the dimensions are given
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G2_(mathematics)

[Credit to Jason]
The symplectic subgroup
$ O_5(\mathbb{R})= 2 \times SO_5(\mathbb{R}) $ is a maximal subgroup of $ SO_6(\mathbb{R}) $. Lifting through the double cover $ SU_4 \to SO_6(\mathbb{R}) $ we have that
$$
4 \circ_2 Sp_2=<iI,Sp_2>
$$
is maximal subgroup of $ SU_4 $.

Every irreducible $ SU_2 $ subgroups of $ SU_4 $ is contained in a conjugate of $ Sp_2 $. See

[Understanding the 4 dimensional irrep of $ SU_2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536082/understanding-the-4-dimensional-irrep-of-su-2/4536205#4536205)

Indeed the containment $ SU(2)_{irr} \subset Sp(2) \subset SU(4) $ is the lift of $ SO(3)_{irr} \subset SO(5) \subset SO(6) $ through the double cover $ SU(4) \to SO(6) $. Here $ SU(2)_{irr} $ is the image of the 4d irrep of $ SU(2) $ and $ SO(3)_{irr} $ is the image of the 5d irrep of $ SO(3) $. Similarly we have that $ N(SU(2)_{irr})=4 \circ_2 SU(2)_{irr} \subset N(Sp(2))=4 \circ_2 Sp_2 \subset SU(4) $ is the lift through the double cover of $ N(SO(3)_{irr})=O(3)_{irr} \subset N(SO_5)=O(5)=S(O_5 \times O_1) \subset SO(6) $. So in particular there is no maximal subgroup of $ SU_4 $ with simple connected component isogeneous to $ SU_2 $. All such groups are $ 4 \circ_2 SU(2)_{irr} \subset 4 \circ_2 Sp_2 $ and thus not maximal.

Finally we consider subgroups with trivial connected component. These are finite since $ SU_4 $ is compact. To be maximal they must at least be primitive. Primitive finite subgroups of $ SU_4 $ are classified by work of Blichfeldt 1911 which was rewritten in modern notation here https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905212 From this we conclude there are $ 4 $ finite groups maximal among the finite subgroups of $ SU_4 $.
The central product
$$
4 \circ_2 2.A_7
$$
of order $ 4(2,520)=10,080 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design)
the central product
$$
4 \circ_2 Sp(4,3)
$$
of order $ 4(25,920)=103,680 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design).
$$
N(2^{2(2)+1})
$$
is the normalizer of an extraspecial 2 group of order $ 32 $. This group has order $ 4(11,520)=46,080 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design). This group is know as the 2 qubit Clifford group in quantum computing. For details see

https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/is-the-clifford-group-a-semidirect-product?noredirect=1&lq=1

Note that this group has order $ 6!2^6=46,080 $ and is the lift through the double cover $ SU_4 \twoheadrightarrow SO_6 $ of $ W(D_6) $. Here $ W(D_6) $ is the subgroup of $ SO_6 $ of signed permutation matrices, the Weyl group of $ D_6 $, which has order $ 6!2^6/2 $. Finally,
$$
4\circ_2 2.S_6
$$
is maximal among the finite subgroups but is actually contained in the group $ N(Sp_2) $ described above. To see this observe that there is a faithful 4d irrep of $ 2.S_6 $ which is quaternionic (Schur indicator -1) so $ 2.S_6 $ is a subgroup of $ Sp_2 $. Thus by adding in $ iI $ we have that $ 4\circ_2 2.S_6 $ is a subgroup of $ N(Sp_2) $.

For references on designs and maximality see [Finite maximal closed subgroups of Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272017/finite-maximal-closed-subgroups-of-lie-groups/4477296#4477296)

So the maximal closed subgroups with trivial identity component are the $ 3 $ finite groups: $ 4\circ_22.A_7,
4\circ_2 Sp(4,3), N(2^{2(2)+1})
$.
This is consistent with the fact
that a maximal $ 2 $-design group is maximal closed ( all $ 3 $ designs are $ 2 $ designs).

Note: $ 2.A_7 $ denotes PerfectGroup(5040,1), the unique perfect group of that order.

Note:
\begin{align*}
& 4\circ_2 2.A_7
 \\
& 4\circ_2 Sp(4,3)
 \\
& N(2^{2(2)+1})\\
\end{align*}
are all 2-designs (at least). The other two designs are 3 other subgroups of $ N(2^{2(2)+1}) $. These six groups are all Lie primitive (not contained in any proper positive dimensional closed subgroup). There is in addition one more Lie primitive group: it corresponds to the $ GL(3,2) $ subgroup of $ A_7 $.

Comment: In my comment that you linked to, I was specifically focusing on simple subgroups of $SU(4)$ containing $SO(4)$.  In particular, I think your list should also have a finite extension of $Sp(2)$, included via the identification of $\mathbb{H}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}^4$.  The extension at least contains $iI$, but I don't know if it has more than 2 components.

Comment: @JasonDeVito this is exactly the sort of feedback I was looking for I'll incorporate all those corrections into my question

Comment: A minor thing to add to my previous comment:  I can now show the maximal proper extension of $Sp(2)$ does indeed just have two components.  Would you like me to write it up as an answer?  Also, $SU(3)$ doesn't have an irreducible rep of dim 4, but it does have a 4 dim rep: the standard rep + trivial.  The corresponding subgroup of $SU(4)$ is the block $SU(3)$, so is not maximal, being contained in $U(3)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Yes, please! And ya you are right that $ SU(3) $ has a 4d rep but all reducible representations are non maximal since they are contained in $ S(U_3 \times U_1) $ or $ S(U_2 \times U_2 ) $ as you say ( in my question I use irrep as short hand for irreducible representation, I think the only thing I claim is that $ SU_3 $ has no 4d irreps?).

Comment: Sorry to be confusing.  There is nothing wrong in what you wrote above, I was just clarifying.  I hadn't though about it previously, but it seems the following is true:  For $G\in \{SU(n), SO(n), Sp(n)\}$, a closed subgroup $H\subseteq G$ is not maximal if the corresponding $n$-dim representation is reducible.  In particular, in terms of classifying maximal subgroups, one only needs to consider irreducible reps.  You probably already knew this ;-).  I'll write the answer about $Sp(2)$ now.

Comment: I did already know that! But usually its the other way around I'm reading your posts and things that are obvious to you are all new thoughts to me! Indeed you can go further and and say that a closed subgroup $ H $ of $ G \in \{ SU(n),SO(n),Sp(n) \} $ is not maximal unless the corresponding $ n $-dim representation is primitive or $ H $ is the normalizer of some block diagonal subgroup. So to amend what you said above (and my previous comment) there is exactly one example $ H=S(U_3 \times U_1) $ which is maximal even though the corresponding $ 4 $-d representation is reducible.

Comment: For a definition of primitive see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468936/primitive-subgroup-of-su-n-contained-in-maximal-finite-subgroup it basically just means block diagonal plus permutations of the blocks ( for example this is exactly the kind of extra stuff that you get when you pass from a group of block diagonal matrices like $ S(U_2 \times U_2) $ to its normalizer).

Comment: Do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that $N:=N_{SU(4)}(Sp(2))$ is a maximal subgroup of $Sp(2)$, and that $N = Sp(2) \cup iI Sp(2)$.

To see this, consider the double covering $\pi:SU(4)\rightarrow SU(4)/\{\pm I\}\cong SO(6)$.  Note that $-I\in Sp(2)\subseteq SU(4)$, so $\pi|_{Sp(2)}$ is the double covering $Sp(2)\rightarrow SO(5)$.  Up to conjugacy, there is an essentially unique $SO(5)\subseteq SO(6)$, the usual block form.

So, instead of studying $Sp(2)\subseteq SU(4)$, we'll study $SO(5)\subseteq SO(6)$ and pull the information back via $\pi$.

**Proposition**:  The only proper subgroup of $SO(6)$ which properly contains $SO(5)$ is $O(5) = \{ \operatorname{diag}(A,\det(A)):A\in O(5)\}$.

**Proof**:  The isotropy action of $SO(5)$ on $S^5 = SO(6)/SO(5)$ is transitive on the unit sphere in $T_{I SO(5)} S^5$, so is, in particular, irreducible.  This, then, implies that $SO(5)$ is maximal among connected groups:  if $SO(5)\subseteq K\subseteq SO(6)$, then on the Lie algebra level, the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ would preserve both $\mathfrak{k}$ and $\mathfrak{k}^\bot$, contradicting irreducibility.  (Here, I'm using the fact that we can naturally identify the isotropy action of $H$ on $T_{I SO(5)} SO(6)/SO(5)$ with $\mathfrak{so}(5)^\bot\subseteq \mathfrak{so}(6)$.)

Since we now know that $SO(5)$ is maximal among connected subgroups of $SO(6)$, and the identity component of a Lie group is always a normal subgroup, it now follows that $N_{SO(6)}(SO(5))$ is a maximal subgroup of $SO(6)$.

Of course, $O(5)\subseteq N_{SO(6)}(SO(5))$, but why is the reverse inclusion true?  Well, every matrix $B\in SO(5)$ fixes the basis vector $e_6$ of $\mathbb{R}^6$, and $\operatorname{span}\{e_6\}$ is the unique subspace of $\mathbb{R}^6$ fixed by all of $SO(5)$.  A simple computation reveals that for any $C\in N_{SO(6)}(SO(5))$, that $CSO(5)C^{-1} = SO(5)$ fixes $Ce_6$.  It follows that $Ce_6 \in \operatorname{span}\{e_6\}$.  Moreover, since $C\in SO(6)$, we must in fact that $Ce_6 = \pm e_6$.  In either case, the fact that $CC^t = I$ now implies that $C\in O(5)$.  $\square$

Now, let's pull that information back to to better understand $N = N_{SU(4)}(Sp(2))$.  It's not too hard to see that $\pi|_N:N\rightarrow N_{SO(6)}(SO(5)$ is a double covering, with $\pi$ mapping $Sp(2)$ and $iI Sp(2)$ to the two different components of $N_{SO(6)}(SO(5))$.

Now, let $g\in N$ be arbitrary.  Since $\pi|_{Sp(2)\cup iI Sp(2)}$ is surjective onto $N_{SO(6)}(SO(5))$, there is an $h\in Sp(2)\cup iI Sp(2)$ with $\pi(g) = \pi(h)$.  Then $gh^{-1}\in \ker \pi = \pm I$, so $g = \pm I h$.  Since both $h, \pm I\in Sp(2)\cup iI Sp(2)$, it follows that $g\in Sp(2)\cup iI Sp(2)$ as well.

Comment: very cool argument using the "accidental" isomorphisms $ SU(4) \cong Spin(6) $ and $ Sp(2) \cong Spin(5) $, love it!

Comment: Ok I finally posted a full classification that I'm pretty confident in. One last sanity check I wanted to make, $SO_4$ is a subgroup of $ Sp_2 $ right?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  No, I don't think $SO(4)$ is a subgroup of $Sp(2)$.   The complex $4$-dim representation of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ given by $SU(2)\rightarrow SU(2)\rightarrow SO(4)\subseteq SU(4)$ is irreducible, so it is precisely one of real, quaternionic, or complex.  As it's obviously real, it cannot be quaternionic.

Answer (score 1):

The full list of maximal subgroups is:

Type I (normalizer of maximal connected subgroup)
\begin{align*}
& U(3) \cong S(U(3) \times U(1)) \\
& S(U(2) \times U(2)):2 \\
& 4 \circ_2 Sp(2)  
\end{align*}
Type II (finite maximal closed subgroup)
\begin{align*}
&4\circ_2 2.A_7
 \\
&4\circ_2 Sp(4,3)
 \\
&N(2^{2(2)+1})
\end{align*}
Type III (normalizer of a subgroup which is connected but not maximal connected)
\begin{align*}
& N(T^3)=S(U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1)) : S_4\\
& SO(4)\cdot 4  \\
\end{align*}

Note that $ S(U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1)) $ is contained in $ S(U(3) \times U(1)) $ above. And $ SO(4) $ is contained in $ Sp(2) $. However $ SO(4) \cdot 4 $ is not contained in $ 4 \circ_2 Sp(2) $.

Note on notation. $ : $ means split extension (semidirect product). $ \cdot $ means nonsplit extension. $ \circ $ denotes central product, in all cases here we have $ 4 \circ_2 H $ is just the group generated by $ H $ and $ iI $ but that group is not a direct product since already $ -I \in H $, we get a central product essentially with two $ H $ components.

Here all the $ N $ denote normalizer. Recall that a positive dimensional (type I and type III above) maximal subgroup of a simple Lie group equals the full normalizer of its identity component.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605784.pdf
classifies all maximal closed subgroups of $ SU(n) $ whose identity component is not simple (here trivial counts as simple). According to table 5 the maximal closed subgroups of $ SU(4) $ of this type are:

The normalizer of the maximal torus (row 4 table 5, $ \ell=4, p=1 $)
$$
 N(T)=S(U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1)) : S_4
$$
As well as (row 1 table 5, $ p=3,q=1 $ )
$$
S(U(3) \times U(1) )\cong U(3) 
$$
and the normalizer of $ S(U(2) \times U(2))= \{\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}:A,B\in U(2),det(A)det(B)=1 \} $ which is a split extension (row 1 table 5 $ p=q=2 $)
$$
< S(U(2) \times U(2)),SWAP_{\oplus}> \cong S(U(2) \times U(2)):2
$$
where the normalizing matrix $ SWAP_{\oplus}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 &  0 \end{bmatrix} $ swaps the two blocks in the direct sum. This is the lift of $ S(O(4) \times O(2) ) $ through the double cover $ SU(4) \to SO(6) $.

Next there is (row 3 table 5, $ p=2 $)
$$
<SU(2) \otimes SU(2), \zeta_8 SWAP_\otimes>
$$
where the matrix $ SWAP_\otimes=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $ swaps the two tensor factors. Here the identity component $ SU(2) \otimes SU(2) $ contains $ -I=(\zeta_8 SWAP_\otimes)^4 $, but does not contain $ iI=(\zeta_8 SWAP_\otimes)^2 $, so the full normalizer is the nonsplit extension $ SU(2) \otimes SU(2) \cdot 4 $. This subgroup is conjugate to the normalizer of the standard $ SO(4) $ subgroup
$$
 SO(4) \cdot 4 
$$
and we prefer to write it that way. This is the lift of $ S(O(3) \times O(3))\cdot 2 $ through the double cover $ SU(4) \to SO(6) $. For more details see

[Is $ SU_2 \otimes SU_2 $ conjugate to $ SO_4(\mathbb{R}) $ in $ SU_4 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397313/so-4-mathbbr-and-su-2-otimes-su-2-subgroups-of-su-4?rq=1)

Next, we consider maximal closed subgroups with nontrivial simple connected component. [Credit to Jason for pretty much all the group with simple identity component stuff]

By dimension, such a subgroup would be isogeneous to $ SU(2),SU(3),Sp(2) $ or $ G_2 $.

There is no 4d irreps of $ SU(3) $ since the dimension of $ SU(3) $ irreps are given by the formula
$$
\frac{(m_1+1)(m_2+1)(m_1+m_2+2)}{2}
$$

Similarly there are no 4d irreps of $ G_2 $ since the dimensions are given
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G2_(mathematics)

The symplectic subgroup
$ O(5)= 2 \times SO(5) $ is a maximal subgroup of $ SO(6) $. Lifting through the double cover $ SU(4) \to SO(6) $ we have that
$$
4 \circ_2 Sp(2)=<iI,Sp(2)>
$$
is maximal subgroup of $ SU(4) $.

Every irreducible $ SU(2) $ subgroups of $ SU(4) $ is contained in a conjugate of $ Sp(2) $. See

[Understanding the 4 dimensional irrep of $ SU_2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536082/understanding-the-4-dimensional-irrep-of-su-2/4536205#4536205)

Indeed the containment $ SU(2)_{irr} \subset Sp(2) \subset SU(4) $ is the lift of $ SO(3)_{irr} \subset SO(5) \subset SO(6) $ through the double cover $ SU(4) \to SO(6) $. Here $ SU(2)_{irr} $ is the image of the 4d irrep of $ SU(2) $ and $ SO(3)_{irr} $ is the image of the 5d irrep of $ SO(3) $. Similarly we have that $ N(SU(2)_{irr})=4 \circ_2 SU(2)_{irr} \subset N(Sp(2))=4 \circ_2 Sp(2) \subset SU(4) $ is the lift through the double cover of $ N(SO(3)_{irr})=O(3)_{irr} \subset N(SO(5))=O(5)=S(O(5) \times O(1)) \subset SO(6) $. So in particular there is no maximal subgroup of $ SU(4) $ with simple connected component isogeneous to $ SU_2 $. All such groups are $ 4 \circ_2 SU(2)_{irr} \subset 4 \circ_2 Sp(2) $ and thus not maximal.

Finally we consider subgroups with trivial connected component. These are finite since $ SU(4) $ is compact. To be maximal they must at least be primitive. Primitive finite subgroups of $ SU(4) $ are classified by work of Blichfeldt 1911 which was rewritten in modern notation here https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905212 From this we conclude there are $ 4 $ finite groups maximal among the finite subgroups of $ SU(4) $.
The central product
$$
4 \circ_2 2.A_7
$$
of order $ 4(2,520)=10,080 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design)
the central product
$$
4 \circ_2 Sp(4,3)
$$
of order $ 4(25,920)=103,680 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design).
$$
N(2^{2(2)+1})
$$
is the normalizer of an extraspecial 2 group of order $ 32 $. This group has order $ 4(11,520)=46,080 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design). This group is know as the 2 qubit Clifford group in quantum computing. For details see

https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25591/is-the-clifford-group-a-semidirect-product?noredirect=1&lq=1

Note that this group has order $ 6!2^6=46,080 $ and is the lift through the double cover $ SU(4) \twoheadrightarrow SO_6 $ of $ W(D_6) $. Here $ W(D_6) $ is the subgroup of $ SO_6 $ of signed permutation matrices, the Weyl group of $ D_6 $, which has order $ 6!2^6/2 $. Finally,
$$
4\circ_2 2.S_6
$$
is maximal among the finite subgroups but is actually contained in the group $ N(Sp(2)) $ described above. To see this observe that there is a faithful 4d irrep of $ 2.S_6 $ which is quaternionic (Schur indicator -1) so $ 2.S_6 $ is a subgroup of $ Sp(2) $. Thus by adding in $ iI $ we have that $ 4\circ_2 2.S_6 $ is a subgroup of $ N(Sp(2)) $.

For references on designs and maximality see [Finite maximal closed subgroups of Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272017/finite-maximal-closed-subgroups-of-lie-groups/4477296#4477296)

So the maximal closed subgroups with trivial identity component are the $ 3 $ finite groups: $ 4\circ_22.A_7,
4\circ_2 Sp(4,3), N(2^{2(2)+1})
$.
This is consistent with the fact
that a maximal $ 2 $-design group is maximal closed ( all $ 3 $ designs are $ 2 $ designs).

Note: $ 2.A_7 $ denotes PerfectGroup(5040,1), the unique perfect group of that order.

Note:
\begin{align*}
& 4\circ_2 2.A_7
 \\
& 4\circ_2 Sp(4,3)
 \\
& N(2^{2(2)+1})\\
\end{align*}
are all 2-designs (at least). The other 2- designs are three other subgroups of $ N(2^{2(2)+1}) $. These six groups are all Lie primitive (not contained in any proper positive dimensional closed subgroup). There is in addition one more Lie primitive group: it corresponds to the $ SL(3,2)\cong PSL(2,7) $ subgroup of $ A_7 $/ the $ SL(2,7) $ subgroup of $ 2.A_7 $.

Comment: Literally brilliant.