# Understanding the 4 dimensional irrep of $ SU_2 $

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

The 2d irrep of $ SU_2 $ is just the defining irrep
$$
SU_2:=\left\{ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \beta \\ 
-\overline{\beta} & \overline{\alpha}
\end{bmatrix} : |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1
\right\}
$$
The 3d irrep of $ SU_2 $ is the subgroup
$$
SO_3(\mathbb{R})
$$
of $ U_3 $. This is the adjoint representation of $ SU_2 $.

I want to better understand the $ 4d $ irrep of $ SU_2 $. Is there some well known subgroup of $ U_4 $ that is the image of a $ 4d $ irrep of $ SU_2 $? For example can we think of the $ 4d $ irrep of $ SU_2 $ as a subgroup of $ SU_2 \otimes SU_2 $? Or perhaps as a subgroup of the $ 10 $ dimensional symplectic subgroup $ Sp_2 $ of $ U_4 $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the $(n+1)$-dimensional irrep of $SU(2)$ is the $n^{th}$ [symmetric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_power) $S^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$, which can be described explicitly as the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in two variables. So the $4$-dimensional irrep is $S^3(\mathbb{C}^2)$, with basis $\{ x^3, x^2 y, xy^2, y^3 \}$, where $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \alpha & \beta \\ - \overline{\beta} & \overline{\alpha} \end{array} \right]$ acts via extending the action $x \mapsto \alpha x - \overline{\beta} y$ and $y \mapsto \beta x + \overline{\alpha} y$ by multiplication. (Here I'm using the convention that $x$ and $y$ correspond to the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$. There's another convention where we consider polynomial functions on $\mathbb{C}^2$ rather than the symmetric power, which is the dual of this representation, but all these reps are self-dual anyway.)

This representation is quaternionic; to see this we use the fact that the defining representation $\mathbb{C}^2$ is quaternionic, so admits an antilinear map $J : \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ satisfying $J^2 = -1$. Then $J^{\otimes 3} : (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 3} \to (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 3}$ is again an antilinear map squaring to $-1$ and it induces a map with that same property on $S^3(\mathbb{C}^2)$. So the corresponding image of $SU(2)$ in $SU(4)$ is contained in a conjugate of $Sp(2)$ but not of $SO(4)$. Presumably the corresponding map $Sp(1) \to Sp(2)$ has some nice quaternionic description but I don't know it.

Comment: Dmytro Yeroshkin wrote code for computing some of these representations in coordinates, just to see them.  The map $Sp(1)\rightarrow Sp(2)$ sends an element $a+bj$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb{C})$ to $\begin{bmatrix} a^3 & b^3 & \sqrt{3}ab^2 & \sqrt{3}a^2b\\ -\overline{b}^3 & \overline{a}^3 & -\sqrt{3}\overline{a}^2\overline{b} & \sqrt{3}\overline{a}\overline{b}^2\\ \sqrt{3}a\overline{b}^2 & \sqrt{3}b\overline{a}^2 & |a|^2 \overline{a} -2|b|^2\overline{a} & |b|^2 \overline{b} - 2|a|^2\overline{b}\\ -\sqrt{3}a^2\overline{b} & \sqrt{3}b^2\overline{a} & 2|a|^2b - |b|^2b & |a|^2a-2a|b|^2\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: (I think I typed the matrix correctly, but could have made a mistake with signs/complex conjugates.  Any mistakes are mine, not Dmytro's.  Also, I don't recall if one uses elements of the form $a+jb$ or $a+bj$....)

Comment: @JasonDeVito is this code publicly available?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  He didn't make it available to me, but I also didn't ask.  Using Qiaochu's description, it shouldn't be *too* hard to implement in maple...

Comment: Do you have any idea what the normalizer of this $ SU_2 $ subgroup of $ SU_4 $ is? Is it just $ SU_2 \times SU_2 $?

Comment: Another interesting perspective is that $ SU(2)_{irr} \subset Sp(2) \subset SU(4) $ is the lift of $ SO(3)_{irr} \subset SO(5) \subset SO(6) $ through the double cover $ SU(4) \to SO(6) $. Here $ SU(2)_{irr} $ is the image of the 4d irrep of $ SU(2) $ and $ SO(3)_{irr} $ is the image of the 5d irrep of $ SO(3) $

Comment: Does this imply in general that the even dimensional irreps of $ SU(2) $ are always symplectic?