# Is the irreducible $ SU(3) $ subgroup of $ SU(6) $ maximal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, maximal-subgroup

Is the 6 dimensional $ (2,0) $ irrep of $ SU(3) $ maximal in $ SU(6) $?

For those of you who are interested in context, I started wondering this the other day when I tried to write down the maximal subgroups of $ SU(6) $. My guess so far is that the full list of maximal (proper closed) subgroups of $ SU(6) $ is:

Type I (normalizer of maximal connected subgroup)
\begin{align*}
& U(5) \cong S(U(5) \times U(1)) \\
& S(U(4) \times U(2)) \\
& S(U(3) \times U(3))\rtimes S_2 \\
& 6 \circ_2 Sp(3)  \\
& 6 \circ_2 SO(6)  \\
& 6 \circ_3 SU(3)_{irr}
\end{align*}
Type II (finite maximal closed subgroup, for the last 2 groups GAP subscripts are used to label the center and the outer automorphisms when multiple groups of this structure description exist)
\begin{align*}
& 6.A_7
 \\
&6.PSL(3,4).2_1
 \\
&6_1.PSU(4,3).2_2
\end{align*}
Type III (normalizer of a subgroup which is connected but not maximal connected)
\begin{align*}
& N(T^6)=S(U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1)) \rtimes S_6\\
&S( U(2) \times U(2) \times U(2) ) \rtimes S_3\\
\end{align*}

Note on notation. $ \rtimes $ means split extension (semidirect product). $ \cdot $ means nonsplit extension. $ \circ $ denotes central product, in most cases here we have $ 6 \circ_2 H $, which is just the group generated by $ H $ and $ \zeta_6I $ but that group is not a direct product since already $ -I \in H $, we get a central product essentially with three $ H $ components. Similar idea for $ 6 \circ_3 SU(3)_{irr} $ having two components.

Here $ N $ denotes normalizer. Recall that a positive dimensional (type I and type III above) maximal subgroup of a simple Lie group equals the full normalizer of its identity component.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605784.pdf
classifies all maximal closed subgroups of $ SU(n) $ whose identity component is not simple (here trivial counts as simple). According to table 5 the maximal closed subgroups of $ SU(4) $ of this type are:

The normalizer of the maximal torus (row 4 table 5, $ \ell=6, p=1 $)
$$
 N(T)=S(U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1) \times U(1)) \rtimes S_6
$$
and (row 4 of table 5, $ \ell=3, p=2 $)
$$
S( U(2) \times U(2) \times U(2) ) \rtimes S_3
$$
As well as (row 1 table 5, $ p=5,q=1 $ )
$$
S(U(5) \times U(1) )\cong U(5) 
$$
and (row 1 table 5, $ p=4,q=2 $ )
$$
S(U(4) \times U(2) ) 
$$
and the normalizer of $ S(U(3) \times U(3))= \{\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}:A,B\in U(3),det(A)det(B)=1 \} $ which is a split extension (row 1 table 5 $ p=q=3 $)
$$
< S(U(3) \times U(3)),SWAP_{\oplus}> \cong S(U(3) \times U(3)) \rtimes S_2
$$
where the normalizing matrix $ SWAP_{\oplus}=\begin{bmatrix}  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $ swaps the two blocks in the direct sum.

Next, we consider maximal closed subgroups with nontrivial simple connected component.

By dimension, such a subgroup would be isogeneous to $ SU(2),SU(3),Sp(2), G_2, SU(4), SO(7), Sp(3), SU(5), SO(8) $ of dimensions $ 3,8,10,14,21,21,24,28 $ respectively.

Of these the only one with 6d irreps are: 6d irrep of $ SU(2) $, the $ (2,0) $  6d  irrep of $ SU(3) $, fundamental irrep of $ Sp(3) $,

Of these only
$$
6 \circ_2 Sp(2)=<\zeta_6 I,Sp(3)>
$$
is maximal subgroup of $ SU(6) $.

Even dimensional irreps of $ SU(2) $ are always symplectic so all $ SU(2) $ subgroups of $ SU(6) $ are contained in a conjugate of $ Sp(3) $. See

[Understanding the 4 dimensional irrep of $ SU_2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536082/understanding-the-4-dimensional-irrep-of-su-2/4536205#4536205)

Finally we consider subgroups with trivial connected component. These are finite since $ SU(6) $ is compact. To be maximal they must at least be primitive. For example there is a very large $ 6 \circ_2 2.J_2 $ subgroup of $ SU(6) $ but it is not maximal because it is not even Lie primitive: it is contained in $ 6 \circ_2 Sp(3) $. Also there is an $ A_7 $ subgroup that is not Lie primitive, it is contained in $ SO(6) $ since it is the standard $ A_{n+1} $ subgroup of $ SO(n) $ arising from the deleted permutation representation.

Even Lie primitive subgroups may not be maximal if they are contained in another larger Lie primitive finite subgroup. For example there is a subgroup $ 3.A_7 \subset 6.PSU(4,3) \subset SU(6)  $ which is Lie primitive but not maximal.

A maximal finite subgroup which is irreducible in the adjoint representation is always a maximal closed subgroup. This includes the following subgroups
The central product
$$
6.A_7
$$
of order $ 6(2,520)=15,120 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 2-design)
$$
6.PSL(3,4).2_1
$$
of order $ 6(20,160)2 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design).
$$
6_1.PSU(4,3).2_2
$$
of order $ 6(3,265,920)2 $ (maximal closed since it is maximal finite and a 3-design).

For references on designs and maximality see [Finite maximal closed subgroups of Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272017/finite-maximal-closed-subgroups-of-lie-groups/4477296#4477296)

This is consistent with the fact
that a maximal $ 2 $-design group is maximal closed ( all $ 3 $ designs are $ 2 $ designs).